# Read Json object and put the values in a List of string

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2010

Platform: C#
IDE: Visual Studio 2010

I am trying to read all the values from json object and put it in the list of string , for which I am doing Json deserialize but it throws me error...

Here is what I have tried

```
List<string> lstPName = new List<string>();
JavaScriptSerializer strJsonSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

localhost.Pstats objStats = new localhost.Pstats();

var strJson = objStats.GetAutoCompleteData(txtSearchBox.Text.Trim());

lstPName = strJsonSer.DeserializeObject<string>(strJson);
```

Here is what the Json object holds

```
[{"PlayerName":"WA Mota"},{"PlayerName":"Atif Ahmed"}]
```

So, I need the player name value to be added in the list...

Comment: you should try using
lstPName = strJsonSer.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(strJson);

Comment: It says its a type but used like a variable

Comment: use json.net from nuget, it's much better:
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>("Your json string")

Comment: Ok, so how do I deserialize then

Comment: List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>("Your json string")
then the key will be: "PlayerName", and the value will be the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and straightforward solution:

```
var strJson = "[{\"PlayerName\":\"WA Mota\"},{\"PlayerName\":\"Atif Ahmed\"}]";
var strJsonSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var list = new List<string>();
var result = strJsonSer.DeserializeObject(strJson) as object[];
if (result != null)
{
    foreach (Dictionary<string, object> x in result)
    {
        list.Add(x["PlayerName"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Or, if you are preferring LINQ - you can use instead of `foreach` loop something like:

```
list = result
    .Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()
    .Select(x => x["PlayerName"].ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Key idea: `DeserializeObject` used for parsing JSON data like yours gives you array of `Dictionary<string, object>` where key is JSON property name and value is JSON property value. Size of array equals to objects count in your JSON data.